# How can a I get a constant in smarty?

Tags: php, smarty, constants

I got a problem with Smarty and constants. I got three constant especified in a file:

```
DEFINE('ARTICLE_COLOUR_10', 'Light green');
DEFINE('ARTICLE_COLOUR_11', 'Claret'); // Bordó
DEFINE('ARTICLE_COLOUR_12', 'Yellow');
```

In DB I save only the numbers (10, 11, 12) and I send those numbers through this var

```
$sql_query_int = mysqli_query($connectdb, "SELECT colour FROM stock WHERE product='$articleId'");    
$smarty->assign('colours', $sql_query_int);
```

In TPL I get those numbers

```
{foreach from=$colours key=field item=value}
    {$value.colour}<br>
{/foreach}
```

Now I want to get the variable ARTICLE_COLOUR_$value.colour; I tried with three different ways but I couldn't get the complete variable.

```
{$smarty.const.ARTICLE_COLOUR_{$value.colour}}
{$smarty.const.ARTICLE_COLOUR_$value.colour}
{$smarty.const.ARTICLE_COLOUR_value.colour}
```

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in C:\xampp\htdocs/templates/default/tpl\article.tpl line 10]: syntax error: $smarty.$value.colour is an invalid reference (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 2169) in C:\xampp\htdocs\inc\smarty\Smarty.class.php on line 1109

I will be grateful for your help with this problem and forgiveness if this question is misspelled, my English is not very advanced.

Comment: is this true `$sql_query_int = [10, 11, 12];` ? I mean is it an array or a string?

Comment: Thanks was looking for {{$smarty.const.MY_CONST}} ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{constant("ARTICLE_COLOUR_{$value.colour}")}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get the value of a class constant in a smarty template you can use php `constant()` function.

```
<?php

namespace \MyNamespace;

class MyClass
{
    const FOO = "Bar";
}
```

In the template file:

```
{constant('\MyNamespace\MyClass::FOO')}
```

and this outputs the value of the constant.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try $colours|@var_dump
check $value.colour is assigned.

or try assign colours array

```
{assign var='colours' value=','|explode:"10,11,12"}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a way that will probably work (in Smarty 3 at least), but involves calling `get_defined_constants` from smarty:

```
{$sysconst=get_defined_constants()}
{$articlevar='ARTICLE_COLOUR_'|cat:$value.colour}

{$sysconst.$articlevar}
```

This is kind of a hack, though... the proper way to do what you want would be to use regular arrays or variables instead of constants and assign them to smarty the usual way